# What is the benefit to keep persistence.xml in application with Spring Boot Data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Except conveniently modify entity information in xml instead of hard-coded in Java?

I see quite a few examples with `Spring data jpa` / `hibernate` from `Spring Boot`, some use `persistence.xml` to register entity class, some don't.

Just wondering what is the benefit to do so, if entity package can be specified in the application context (or not)?

Comment: Benefit of using persistence.xml ? It is STANDARD JPA if you do that, so usable in JavaEE in the future if you used that. If you put stuff in Spring then it is not standard

Comment: @Neil Stockton do you mean J2EE 6 container will not support application without persistence.xml? Like GlassFish or WebLogic 12c?

Comment: I said "usable in JavaEE" (i.e J2EE 6 7 or whatever, JavaEE). How would that mean "not support it" ?! JPA is a java standard (of which persistence.xml is part), Spring is not. JavaEE is a Java standard.

Comment: @Neil Stockton I see, well if Spring framework is yet a standard so it won't be such a matter if a Spring application's DAO layer follow certain standard?